# How to sort multiple data in a specific column into a new table

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with different data input in a column. What I need is to sort all the data into a new table in which all values will be in the corresponding row.

```
Example 1   0,29    Santolinatriene
            0,18    Thujene <alpha->
            1,43    Pinene <alpha->
            0,36    2,2-Dimethyl-5-methylene norbornane
            13,36   Sabinene
            9,09    Pinene <beta->
            0,25    Myrcene
            0,15    Yomogi alcohol

Example 2   0,18    Pinene <alpha->
            0,1     2,2-Dimethyl-5-methylene norbornane
            1,52    Sabinene
            0,9     Pinene <beta->
            0,08    Myrcene
            0,04    Yomogi alcohol
```

You can see that not all the names occur in all examples. I have around 20 examples with over 300 compound names per example. Photos are just as a model. 
I would like to sort all the data into new table in which all the compound names that occur (column C on the photos above) have their corresponding value (column B on the photo above) for each example separated.

For the information on the photos that would look something like this:

```
                      Example 1    Example 2
Santolinatriene        0,29         **0 or blank**
Thujene <alpha->       0,18         **0 or blank**
Pinene <alpha->        1,43         0,18
2,2-Dimethyl-5-methyl  0,36         0,1
Sabinene               13,36        1,52
Pinene <beta->         9,09         0,9
Myrcene                0,25         0,08
Yomogi alcohol         0,15         0,04
```

If I try to sort the data by searching and typing I wouldn't be done before Christmas, I have more 5000+ rows...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do not include PNG files.  Rather copy / paste the text values and surround each set with braces { }.  Please revise your text above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- make a list of unique compounds names - your result row names
- make a list of unique example names - your result columns

You can use the excel function "Remove Duplicates" for this.

Paste them somewhere to create a frame around the result values like you did above (empty for now).

- Add a fourth column to your raw examples, called "helper column". Assuming your examples start in cell A1, put formula in cell A2: `=IF(A2="", LEFT(D1,1), A2) & C2`. This concatenates the example name to the front of each compound name (e.g. "Example1Sabinene". Scroll down the formula until the column is filled for every row for each example.
- in the top left cell in the results frame, put formula: `=INDEX($B:$B, MATCH(B$1&$A2,$D:$D ), 0)`. The first column in INDEX are the compound values (e.g. "0,18"), MATCH gets the combination of example name and compound name, and finds the right row in the 'helper column'. Now just scroll the formula across and down, and you have your answer.

Comment: Right now I have:
> Text "Example 1" in column A.
> Values e.g. "0,18" in column B.
> Compound names e.g. "Sabinene" in column C.
> Texts like "Example1Sabinene" in column D.



How do I now format formula that you have listed last in your answer and where to put it?

Comment: Regarding the fomula in my last answer, using the unique compound names and unique example names you created go to another sheet of the workbook and paste them there, so that in the first column as rows you get the compound names, and in the first row as column names you get the example names. Cell A1 will be blank. I'll call this the "results frame". Now paste my formula into cell B2 and scroll it across and down.

Comment: Next, ensure that column B and D in the formula match with the correct columns an your source data sheet, and make sure K and J match with the correct row and column in the results frame.